# Scala _ Placeholders (How does this code function?)

Tags: scala, functional-programming, placeholder

I am learning Scala (coming from a background of mostly Java). I am trying to wrap my head around the following code:

```
object Main {
  def main(args : Array[String]) {
    for (file <- filesEnding(".txt"))
      println(file.getName)
  }

  private val filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles

  def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) =
    for (file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName))
        yield file

  def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))
  /* Other matcher functions */
}
```

In particular I am confused where Scala gets the value for `_` in each of the matcher functions. I can see that `filesEnding` is called with an argument of `.txt`. That argument is assigned to `query`. `filesEnding` then calls `filesMatching` with an argument consistent with a `String => Boolean` function. Finally I can see that `file.getName` is what eventually replaces the `_` placeholder.

What I don't get is how Scala knows to put `file.getName` in place of `_`. I am having trouble tracing this code in my head and the eclipse debugger isn't much help in this situation. Can somebody walk me through what is happening in this code?

Comment: Just a little reminder / advice on this regard: try to avoid the underscore as much as possible. It will save you some trouble!

Comment: @Andreas I don't see why I should try to avoid the underscore as much as possible. For simple arguments to methods like `filter`, `map`, etc. it makes perfect sense, does not cause trouble and reduces clutter.

Comment: Yes for very simple statements it works OK, of course it's designed to work ;) but the problem is (IMHO) that it has about! 13 different meanings in scala.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `_` is just a shorthand for making an anonymous function:

```
_.endsWith(query)
```

is the same as the anonymous function

```
fileName => fileName.endsWith(query)
```

This function is then fed as the argument `matcher` to `filesMatching`. Inside that function you can see the call

```
matcher(file.getName)
```

This calls the anonymous function with `file.getName` as the `_` argument (which I called `fileName` in the explicit example).

Comment: Looks like it works only if anonymous function accepts one parameter. Is it possible to use it for more than one param ? If not what part of lang specification explains it ?

Answer (score 13):

If you write `_.someMethod(someArguments)`, this desugars to `x => x.someMethod(someArguments)`, so `filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))` desugars to `filesMatching(x => x.endsWith(query))`.

So `filesMatching` is called with `matcher` being the function `x => x.endsWith(query)`, i.e. a function which takes one argument `x` and calls `x.endsWith(query)` on that argument.

Comment: Oh, I like that term, "desugars." I'm going to start using that.

Comment: @KPthunder "Diets to"