# Understanding Scala: passing functions as arguments

Tags: scala

I'm starting to learn Scala and I've come across a snippet from the Programming in Scala textbook which I don't quite understand. Was hoping some one could help me?

This is from Listing 9.1 from Programming in Scala, 2nd Edition.

```
object FileMatcher {
    private def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
}

private def filesMatching(matcher: String => Boolean) = 
    for (file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName)) yield file

def filesEnding(query: String) = 
    filesMatching(_.endsWith(query)) // ???

def filesContaining(query: String) = 
    filesMatching(_.contains(query)) // ???

def filesRegex(query: String) = 
    filesMatching(_.matches(query)) // ???
```

I'm a little confused with the lines that have `// ???`. Does the use of the `_` somehow create an anonymous function that is passed to `filesMatching`? Or does the `_` have nothing to do with this, and instead the compiler sees that `filesMatching` requires a function and therefore doesn't execute `_.endsWith(query)` as an expression but instead makes the expression a function?

Comment: There aren't any lines with `// ???` above. Maybe you forgot to add those?

Comment: Sorry about that, have added the `// ???` now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala \_ Placeholders (How does this code function?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880407/scala-placeholders-how-does-this-code-function)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**extended definition**

Anonymous function are defined, in their more verbose and complete form, as

```
(a: A, b: B, ...) => function body //using a, b, ...
```

E.g.

```
(a: String, b: String) => a ++ b // concatenates 2 Strings
```

---

**inferred types**

if the context provides the needed information (as when a higher order function expects a specific signature for its function arguments), you can omit the parameters' types, as

```
(a, b, ...) => function body //using a, b, ...
```

E.g.

```
val l = List(1, 2, 3)

//you can omit the type because filter on List[Int] expects a (Int => Boolean)
l.filter(i => i < 3)
```

---

**placeholder syntax**

Finally you can use a shorter form still, if your parameters are used once each and in the same order that you declare them, by the function body, as

```
_ ++ _ // which is equivalent to (a, b) => a ++ b
```

Each `_` is a placeholder for the function's arguments

E.g.

`filesMatching`'s argument is a function of type `String => Boolean` so you can use

```
_.endsWith(query) // equivalent to (s: String) => s.endsWith(query)
_.contains(query) // equivalent to (s: String) => s.contains(query)
_.matches(query)  // equivalent to (s: String) => s.matches(query)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `_` as used here is shorthand for a function argument. Thus `filesMatching(_.endsWith(query))` is equivalent to `filesMatching(f => f.endsWith(query))`. As `filesMatching` has as argument a function of `String => Boolean`, the compiler can infer that `f` is expected to be a `String` here. So you are right that this expression is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of operation is best done by defining function types. I found an excellent demonstration [here](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html). Combined with this post, the demonstration should clarify best practices for passing functions as arguments